# Linphone Android app got crashed in screen size of Tablets

Tags: android, tablet, linphone

I builded a Linphone android open source code and tested in android mobile. It works fine in android mobile. But when I run this app in emulator with  screen size(1024*600), it crashed often. I need to check this crash also occurs Samsung Galaxy Tab 3(specifically). but currently i don't have Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 device with myself. Can anyone provide me the solution to accomplish the above?

this is  my logcat when crashes

```
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655): Cannot start linphone
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startBluetooth(LinphoneManager.java:261)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startLibLinphone(LinphoneManager.java:650)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.createAndStart(LinphoneManager.java:358)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at org.linphone.LinphoneService.onCreate(LinphoneService.java:167)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-07 10:17:38.037: E/TEST(655):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am getting this exception after commented the `startBluetooth()` method

```
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-100
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at org.linphone.DialerFragment$8.run(DialerFragment.java:666)
03-07 12:38:08.683: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

add below line in application tag of AndroidManifest.xml file. your application is crashed due to OutOfMamoryException. This happedned with me and then i set largHeap to true in AndoridManifest.xml and problem solved.

android:largeHeap="true"

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_linphone_57x57"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
.
.
.
</application>
```

In your case,

if you dont need bluetooth audio in application then comment or add exception in below code.

`startBluetooth();` in `startLibLinphone(Context c)` function of `LinphoneManager.java`.

Try this. it giving error due to bluetooth native support.

Comment: I tested after adding this in my code,but still the crash is happening.

Comment: please add android debug log when app crashes.

Comment: kaushik, i added current log status

Comment: you have OutOfMemoryError. Increase RAM size in emulator and also increase VM Heap to 64 or 128.

One more thing , you can use samsung galaxy note 3 from Samsung real time device. Open this link. 

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

Create account in samsung realtime device and open device in your machine. you can install your apk and test it in any samsung device. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reference,it will be helpful for me,i hope so.

Comment: Welcome jamal. If your problem solved then dont forget to voteup and accept answer. :P ;P :)